# Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a function such that $f(x) = x^3 +x$. Prove that $f$ is onto.

Tags: functions

Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a function such that $f(x) = x^3 +x$. Prove that $f$ is onto.

I know that $f$ is onto if either of the following conditions is satisfied.

1. $Range(f) = Codomain(f)$
2. Each element of Codomain of $f$ has preimage in Domain of $f$.  i.e. for each $y \in \Bbb R$(Codomain), $\exists x \in \Bbb R$(Domain) such that $f(x) = y$

Let $f(x) = y \implies x^3 + x = y$. Here I'm unable to write $x = g(y)$. Please help me.

Comment: Is the function continuous? What are the limits at $\pm\infty$?

Comment: You have to show that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ implies that $x_1 = x_2$

Comment: @GeometryLover he needs to show the function is *surjective*, not *injective*.

Comment: I take this question from a book . In this book continuity is discussed in later chapter. So we can't use concept of continuity.

Comment: Do you happen to have the result that odd-degree polynomials must vanish somewhere? (Note that this is a consequence of continuity too, but it may be the case that this was addressed before)

Comment: @LargestPrime: The claim is equivalent to showing that the polynomial $x^3+x-b$ ($b\in\Bbb R$) has at least one real root. Use Descartes' rule of signs. Or an overkill would be to invoke the fundamental theorem of algebra to prove that any odd degree polynomial with real coefficients has at least one real root.

Comment: @coffeemath I do agree, but that's not relevant towards OP's question. Especially now knowing that they don't have continuity available, I can't possible imagine they have derivatives.

Comment: The easiest way is to use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: That assumes _continuity_, which the OP has said earlier is covered after this, so I don't think OP can use that. Of course, without any such restrictions, IVT is the simplest approach.

Comment: Without continuity, maybe you can use Cardano's formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula

Comment: $f$ is strictly increasing and continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$ so surjectivity follows from the intermediate value theorem.